# Kubuntu doesnt' differentiate *.3mf and *.zip files

Tags: kubuntu, default-programs, zip, mime-type, ark

I can't set different programs for opening the mentioned filetypes in Kubuntu 22.04.
I want to open `*.zip` files with `ark` and `*.3mf` files with `Ultimaker Cura`.

When I try to change the default program via `right click -> properties -> "open with" -> change`, it changes the association for both filetypes. In fact the properties show `Type: zip-archive` for the `*.3mf` files as well.
I'm using Cura as an `AppImage` with [`AppImageLauncher`](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher) and can normally add it as a standard program for files through the context menue.

Even after editing the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and adding the line

```
application/3mf=appimagekit_968bf060d41f38a8b5f435483426a7e5-com.ultimaker.cura.desktop;
```

it won't work, although that is the correct path to associate Cura.

Why is my OS thinking that `*.3mf` files are `*.zip` files and how can i change that?

The command `grep 3mf -r ~/.local/share/mime /usr/share/mime` delivers:

```
/usr/share/mime/types:model/3mf
```

but only because I manually edited it. Still the problem persists.

Comment: I get `model/3mf` not `application/3mf` when I do `xdg-mime query filetype test.3mf`

Comment: I get `application/zip` for some reason... And also after changing the entry in the `~/.config/mimeapps.list` it doesn'affect the behaviour

Comment: Please [edit] with `grep 3mf -r ~/.local/share/mime /usr/share/mime`

Comment: I edited the original post, but as I said I manually edited the contents of that file without success

Comment: The /usr/share/mime/types will get overwritten the next time the dpkg triggers for shared-mime-info run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `model/3mf` mime type was only added in 22.10. A workaround is to backport the definition:

1. Paste the following into `~/.local/share/mime/packages/3mf-askubuntu-1502786-1004020.xml`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
     <mime-type type="model/3mf">
       <comment>3MF document</comment>
       <acronym>3MF</acronym>
       <expanded-acronym>3D Manufacturing Format</expanded-acronym>
       <glob pattern="*.3mf"/>
       <alias type="application/vnd.ms-3mfdocument"/>
       <sub-class-of type="application/zip"/>
     </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
2. Run `update-mime-database -V ~/.local/share/mime`
3. Close and reopen Dolphin file manager

I just took the `*.3mf` definition from the `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml` file from the `shared-mime-info` package on my 23.10 installation. The file types in Kubuntu are detected by `xdg-mime query filetype test.3mf`, which calls `kmimetypefinder5 test.3mf`, which read `{~/.local/share,/usr/share}/mime/{types,mime.cache}`. `update-mime-database` with the verbose flag creates those files from the definitions in the `packages` folder in the same directory.

If you have multiple users, you can create the new file in `/usr/share/mime/packages/` instead and run the analogous update command.